# Flux takeUntil only takes one element

Tags: java, kotlin, project-reactor

Can someone help me understand what is going on here with Flux's `takeUntil` operator?

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    .takeUntil { it < 4 }
    .map { println("Flux:$it") }
    .subscribe()
```

In the console, the only thing that is printed is:

```
Flux:1
```

I expected to see

```
Flux:1
Flux:2
Flux:3
```

Why do I only see one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, note that you are using the `takeUntil()` operator:

> Relay values from this [`Flux`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) until the given [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html?is-external=true) matches. This includes the matching data (unlike [`takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate<? super T>)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-)).
>
> — [Flux (reactor-core 3.4.22)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.22/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html).

Please, note: «until»:

> until the given [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html?is-external=true) matches

To achieve the desired behavior, please, consider using the `takeWhile()` operator instead:

> Relay values from this [`Flux`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) while a predicate returns TRUE for the values (checked before each value is delivered). This only includes the matching data (unlike [`takeUntil(java.util.function.Predicate<? super T>)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeUntil-java.util.function.Predicate-)).
>
> — [Flux (reactor-core 3.4.22)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.22/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html).

Comment: Thank you, the docs were misleading to me.